# pywintypes.error: (2, 'CreateFile', 'The system cannot find the file specified while installing Sitecore Docker images

Tags: powershell, docker, jss, sample

I am following the document https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/developer-tools/en/walkthrough--using-the-getting-started-template.html to create a test sample project for Sitecore Headless Development.

Everything was so smooth till step 7 `.\up.ps1`

On executing step 7, I am getting the below exception.

```
D:\Projects\Core\MyProject\up.ps1 : Container build failed, see errors above.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\up.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,up.ps1
```

[image]

What could be the issue?

Comment: I updated my Docker version and it worked

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has happened because "Docker Desktop" was not running on my machine. I started "Docker Desktop" and execute the script again. I was able to install a sample project for Sitecore Headless Development.
[image]

Comment: A slight variation to this: I restarted Docker Desktop and this issue was resolved for me.

Comment: The reason is the same. Thanks for the update. It would help other viewers.